# why is this define not an expression?

Tags: racket

I can't figure out the problem DrRacket (IDE) complains about with regard to the   `(define (bifurcate f a f_a b f_b)...`  Please advise. The define block is said to be an improper expression, and perhaps an implicit begin.
Note, if I copy and paste the define into the REPL window (and, of course, define the f_a, f_b, etc.) it works fine. Thanks much! 
(p.s., Its rather early-days in my self study of scheme with two to three books)

---

```
#lang racket
;function to return root of y = f(x) where we know solution is in some bracket [a, b]
;subject to a < b and
;sign(f(a)) != sign(f(b))
;
;my version of "search" on pg 67 "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"
;
(define (bifurcate-wrapper f a b)
  (if (or (positive? (* (f a) (f b))) (>= a b)) ;check for erroneous input
      #f 
      (let ((f_a (f a)) (f_b (f b))); initial values, don't recalculate BOTH f(a) and f(b) ea. time
        (define (bifurcate f a f_a b f_b); DrRacket says this define is not an expression...
      (let ((midpoint (/ (+ a b) 2.0)))
    (if (close-enough? a b)
        midpoint
        (let ((f_mid (f midpoint)))
          (cond ((positive? (* f_a f_mid))
                 (bifurcate f midpoint f_mid b f_b))
                ((positive? (* f_mid f_b))
                 (bifurcate f a f_a midpoint f_mid))
                (else midpoint)))))); end of define
        )
  )
) 


(define (close-enough? x y)
  (< (abs (- x y)) 0.001))

(bifurcate-wrapper sin 2.0 4.0) ;expect pi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message is

```
49-unsaved-editor:7:8: begin (possibly implicit): the last form is not an expression
  at: (define (bifurcate f a f_a b f_b) (let ((midpoint (/ (+ a b) 2.0))) (if (close-enough? a b) midpoint (let ((f_mid (f midpoint))) (cond ((positive? (* f_a f_mid)) (bifurcate f midpoint f_mid b f_b)) ((positive? (* f_mid f_b)) (bifurcate f a f_a mid...
  in: (begin (define (bifurcate f a f_a b f_b) (let ((midpoint (/ (+ a b) 2.0))) (if (close-enough? a b) midpoint (let ((f_mid (f midpoint))) (cond ((positive? (* f_a f_mid)) (bifurcate f midpoint f_mid b f_b)) ((positive? (* f_mid f_b)) (bifurcate f a ...
  #(242 502)
```

That's because the only thing in the body of the outer `let` is the definition of `binfurcate`, and a `define` is one of the few things in scheme and Racket that's *not* an expression. `let` allows 0 or more internal `define`s followed by expressions (Possibly mixed with more internal definitions, but it has to end with an expression).

You just have to *call* your `bifurcation` function after defining it so satisfy that requirement. I'd also clean up your indentation (*Racket* menu -> *Reindent All* in DrRacket) and move all those single-line closing parens so they cuddle with the rest in [normal Lispy style](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html#%28part._.Where_to_.Put_.Parentheses%29).

For working SICP problems, also consider installing the [SICP package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html) and using `#lang sicp`. That provides some things that the book assumes are present in the host Scheme that aren't in standard Racket.

Comment: Thanks!  That's perfect.  I understand now, and I'll work on your other suggestions.